# Unity mono 2.0 vs 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

Unity started testing mono/.net 4.6 a little while back. Since these versions are so far apart there is not a concrete list of the biggest features and changes between these two versions.

Is there such a list online? or can someone name the biggest features? 
(I am not that invested into following .net versions ;) )

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but async/await was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5. If this feature comes to Unity, then it will probably replace 'yield' for coroutines.

Comment: @fshauge Not really. That cannot replace coroutine.

Comment: You really have to Google **each** .NET version to see the features and the new API added to them. Note that old Unity supports 3.5 not just 2. Start from 4 and keep going up until 4.6. It will take so much time for someone to do this for you since the list is big.

Comment: @fshauge Coroutines aren't threads. Async is *specifically* threaded.